# Получить код N страниц сайта используя потоки

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Имеем URL: "http://www.site.ru/data/data?pageSize=1000&pageNum=1"
pageNum = 1 - N

Необходимо получить код страниц "pageNum = 1 - N".

Получаю только 4 страницы, а необходимо все "N". Как это сделать!?
Возможно это делается иначе и правильнее, может другим способом!?

У меня получилось нечто следующее...

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Start, Stop: integer;
  Elapsed: integer;
begin
  // Создать паралельный цикл
  TParallel.For(0, 4 - 1,
    procedure(i: integer)
    var
      tasks: array of ITask;
    begin
      Setlength(tasks, 4);      // Длинна массива
      // Создать задачу
      tasks[i] := TTask.Create(
        procedure()
        var
          URL: string;
          text: string;
          IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
        begin
          Start := GetTickCount; // Начало

          IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create();
          URL := 'http://www.site.ru/data/data?pageSize=1000&pageNum=' + inttostr(i + 1);
          text := IdHTTP1.get(URL);

          Stop := GetTickCount; // Окончание

          //Синхронизировать
          TThread.Synchronize(nil,
            procedure()
            begin
              Memo1.Lines.Add(URL + ' = ' + FloatToStr((Stop - Start) / 1000) + ' сек.');
            end);
        end);
      tasks[i].Start; // Стартуем созданное задание.
    end);
end;
```

Получил необходимый результат способом ниже. Возможно это не лучший вариант получения кода страниц.

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  tasks: array of ITask;
  i: integer;

  tQ: TThreadedQueue<integer>;

  Start, Stop: integer;
  Elapsed: integer;
begin
  Start := GetTickCount; // Начало выполнения операций

  tQ := TThreadedQueue<integer>.Create(TThread.ProcessorCount);
  Setlength(tasks, 10);

  for i := Low(tasks) to High(tasks) do
  begin
    tQ.PushItem(i);

    tasks[i] := TTask.Create(
      procedure()
      var
        URL: string;
        text: string;
        IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
        A: integer;
      begin
        IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create();
        A := tQ.PopItem;
        URL := 'http://www.site.ru/data/data?pageSize=1000&pageNum=' + inttostr(A + 1);
        text := IdHTTP1.get(URL);
      end);
    tasks[i].Start;
  end;

  TTask.WaitForAll(tasks);

  Stop := GetTickCount; // Окончание выполнения операций
  ShowMessage(FloatToStr((Stop - Start) / 1000) + ' сек.');
end;
```

Думаю, что есть способы более правильные

Comment: А это вообще надо делать? Сайт твой? Я пару раз так клал сайты, нечаянно. В первый из них меня забанили по IP. С тех пор к многопоточности в своих ботах отношусь аккуратно. Во многих ботах она и не нужна,  на самом деле.

Comment: @SmInc надо, раз уж спрашиваю

Comment: А если заменить константу 4 на N?

Comment: пишите свои парсеры так, чтобы не только свои задачи решать, но и другим проблемы не создавать. забейте на многопоточность,делайте паузы между запросами. сохраняйте уже скачанное куда нибудь на диск, чтобы не качать это заново при повторном запуске парсера, когда он внезапно упадет где нибудь в середине.

Comment: Не один комментарий не помог в решении вопроса.